# jquery for loop not worked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying run a for loop but it is not working. I cannot find error. Please help me to find error of this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
        $('span#active-account').html('10');
        for ( var seconds = 10; i > 5; i-- ) {
            $('span#active-account').html(seconds);
        }
    });
```

Comment: And a for loop subtracting is not going to show a countdown...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding this line:

```
for ( var seconds = 10; i > 5; i-- ) {
```

You need to decide whether you want your variable called `seconds` or `i`. I suspect what you *meant* to do was:

```
for ( var seconds = 10; seconds > 5; seconds-- ) {
```

(based on the fact that you're using `seconds` in the body but not `i`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the same var in the three instances of for statment.
Your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
        $('span#active-account').html('10');
        for ( var i = 10; i > 5; i-- ) {
            $('span#active-account').html(i);
        }
    });
```